# Download file showing in tomcat bin folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I run my war file on Tomcat server then I run my project on chrome and download the xls file from my project and this file showing in tomcat bin folder as well as download folder in our computer.

Please suggest me  how we can stop this download file in tomcat bin folder

thanks

```
String FILE_EXTENSION = ".xlsx";
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
            filename = "SearchPayment_Transactions_" + df.format(new Date()) + FILE_EXTENSION;
            File file = new File(filename);

            // this Writes the workbook
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wb.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            wb.dispose();
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            addActionMessage(filename + " written successfully on disk.");
```

Comment: Where should it go instead, and why? What have you set up to ensure that?

Comment: currently my download file going in two directory 1 is download directory which was ok with me but in 2 is tomcat bin folder  but i don't want that because it was increasing my server size

Comment: Is the XLS file a static resource or dynamic? If it is dynamic, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66433926/edit) your question and provide (part) of the code that generates the XLS file? My guess is: the servlet code puts the XLS file in the working directory of the server process instead of `ServletContext.TEMPDIR`.

Comment: String FILE_EXTENSION = ".xlsx";
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
   filename = "SearchPayment_Transactions_" + df.format(new Date()) + FILE_EXTENSION;
   File file = new File(filename);

   // this Writes the workbook
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
   wb.write(out);
   out.flush();
   out.close();
   wb.dispose();
   fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
   addActionMessage(filename + " written successfully on disk.");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the this problem can be sovled, just by fixing the place you want to created the file

String FILE_EXTENSION = ".xlsx";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
filename = "SearchPayment_Transactions_" + df.format(new Date()) + FILE_EXTENSION;
**File file = new File(*path any fixed directory like temp*\filename);**

As long as you specify the path where you want to generate the file then it will generating only in tht directory. PLease make proper permission is given to path to generate file, and this will solve your issue.

Comment: The servlet's temporary directory `(File) servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR)` is a good choice to store temporary files.

Comment: yeap that is can be used as well, but in case they want to generate in the specific folder the same path can be given as well.

Comment: thanks for your Answer. we can do one thing just file download in download folder. not on server like tomcat and any where else

Answer (score 0):

The file appears twice on your computer, because your servlet code saves the `*.xlsx` file to disk before sending it to your browser. That's the behavior your chose in your code.

Remark however, that `file` in your code is a **relative** path, so the folder you write it is the working directory (according to the OS) of your server. The value of the working directory is not defined in the Servlet Specification and may vary from system to system.

A better solution would be:

- either don't write any file at all and write your data directly to [`ServletResponse#getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream--),
- or write the file to the Servlet's temporary directory, which you can obtain through `(File) servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR)`. E.g. you can replace your `file` variable with:

```java
final File file = new File((File) servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR), filename);
```